# Wordpress comments title

Tags: theme-development, comments

This code:

```
<?php comments_template( '', true ); ?>
```

Outputs:

```
<h3 id="comments-title">
  <h2>
     12 Responses to My Post.
  </h2>
</h3>
(comments template)
```

I don't know where this h2 tag comes from. I want to get rid of that. And customize my comments-title (so there will be h4 instead of h3 and "comments" instead of "Responses". How to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comment markup - both the comments list and the comment reply form, will be in the `comments.php` template file.

The contents of this file are entirely Theme-dependent, so any more-specific help will require the content of `comments.php`.